# Vuex estado boleano de un boton

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

hola estoy trtando de hace un boton que cambie  de trua a false segun haga click, y dependiendo del estado, ejecutar una funcion, como pueod hacerle?, soy muy nuevo en vuex, gracias adjunto un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr:

```
new vuex.Store({
strict: true,
state,  //el estado lo traigo de un archivo externo date:false
mutations:{
showhide:state=>{
state.date=!state.date
console.log(works?)
}
actions:{
//aqui quiero evaluar si mi state.date es verdadero o falso:
let x = state.date
x ? fucniton() : console.log('reject!')
})

//en mi boton tengo:

methods:{
this.$store.dispatch('showhide')
}
```

pero no me funciona, que puedo hacer? gracias!

Comment: Si en lugar de llamar a la mutation llamas a una funcion dentro del action que cambie la mutation no deberias tener problemas... puede ser que no hayas entendido como funciona vuex?

Comment: efectivamente estoy aprendiendo a usarlo, gracias por tu respuesta